# Terraform Escape Single Quotes

Tags: terraform

I am trying to escape single quotes in my terraform script and inventory file.

Terraform script line:

```
list_compute= "${join("\n",formatlist("%s openshift_node_labels="{'region': 'primary', 'zone': 'east'}"", "${module.compute.ops_compute_names}"))}"
```

How do I preserve/escape the single quote around region, primary, zone and east?

Also my template file which is used for rendering:

```
openshift_master_identity_providers=[{'name': 'htpasswd_auth', 'login': 'true', 'challenge': 'true', 'kind': 'HTPasswdPasswordIdentityProvider', 'filename': '/etc/origin/master/htpasswd'}]
```

How do I preserve/escape the single quotes.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem. 
It seems like terraform uses "echo" command to fill target file from the template and adds quotes around each line.
I've tried to escape these quotes with slaches and triple slashes and no effect.
Then i've changed quotes to double quotes and it worked.
Like this:
openshift_master_identity_providers=[{"name": "htpasswd_auth", "login": "true", ...

Comment: Would be good to reformulate your  answer into a real answer that clearly states the solution for the question.